# System.SObjectException: Invalid field T_A__c.Employee_on_Job__r.Id for AggregateResult

Tags: apex, trigger

Employee__c can have several Time entries(T_A__C), so I am calculating the total number of days worked by each employee.

T_A__C has lookup to Employee__C, I am using below trigger on Employee__C, I can save it successfully but when I am editing the Employee__C it is showing me below error -

> FATAL_ERROR System.SObjectException: Invalid field
>   T_A__c.Employee_on_Job__r.Id for AggregateResult

## Trigger:

```
trigger TestTrigger on Employee__c (after insert,after update) {

List<Employee__c> emplIst = new List<Employee__c>();

List<AggregateResult> ar = [Select Sum(Days_in_number__c) daysSum,              T_A__c.Employee_on_Job__r.Id 
                            from T_A__c 
                            Group By  T_A__c.Employee_on_Job__r.Id];
Map<id , Double> map1= new Map<id , Double>();
Set<Id> ids = new Set<Id>();
for(AggregateResult result : ar)
    {
        map1.put((String)result.get('T_A__c.Employee_on_Job__r.Id'),               (Double)result.get('daysSum'));
        ids.add((ID)result.get('T_A__c.Employee_on_Job__r.Id'));
    }

List<Employee__c> o = [Select id, Total_number_of_days_worked__c from Employee__c where id IN : ids];
for(Employee__c opp : o)
{
    opp.Total_number_of_days_worked__c = map1.get(opp.id);
    emplIst.add(opp);
}
if(emplIst.size()>0)
    update emplIst;
}
```

===============

Comment: try to add `Employee_on_Job__c` instead of `T_A__c.Employee_on_Job__r.Id` and in soql use group by `Employee_on_Job__c` field

Answer (score 1):

Add an alias in the aggregate query for `T_A__c.Employee_on_Job__r.Id` as you have already done for `Sum(Days_in_number__c)` and use the alias in the get:

```
... Select Sum(Days_in_number__c) daysSum, T_A__c.Employee_on_Job__r.Id jobId
...
map1.put((Id)result.get('jobId'), (Double)result.get('daysSum'));
```

Aggregate queries generate names such as "expr0" and use those as the names in the `AggregateResult` if you don't supply an alias so best to use an alias so you control the naming.

Answer (score 0):

What you are try to put in map is not field value - but rather path.
at the same time methode you are using 'get' for SObject work with fields: the result is this methode try to pick value of field with name 'T_A__c.Employee_on_Job__r.Id' - and there is no such field.

You should either build formula field to store proper value on objet or create proper methode(or logic) to read parent field value.

please check:

```
sObject acc = [SELECT Owner.Profile.Name FROM Account LIMIT 1];
String profileName = (String)    
acc.getSobject('Owner').getSobject('Profile').get('Name');
```